# Windows Media video playback grows slow after several topology switches

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

Win64, Windows Media Foundation app in C++. I have a handful of topologies and a single media session. The app switches between topologies:

```
TheSession->SetTopology(MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE, NextTopology);
PROPVARIANT v;
InitPropVariantFromInt64(0, &v);
TheSession->Start(&GUID_NULL, &v);
```

It generally works. But I've noticed after some time of this, video playback becomes slow, it skips frames. The machine has CPU aplenty. Frame skipping lasted for at least a minute, wasn't a momentary fluke. After a while, frame skipping is observed on all videos. I have a semi-reliable repro on this condition. When you switch topologies in that state, it goes fine for a short while (~30sec), then slows down. The CPU utilization during the slowdown doesn't spike - it's not CPU. There is *some* resource exhaustion, but not CPU.

When I switch topologies like that, the previous topology is not explicitly stopped. Could it be that some processing for the evicted topology is still running, even though it's not in the session anymore? If so, how does one stop the processing on a disconnected topology? The only idea that comes to mind is calling Stop on the media source of the evicted topology.

Stopping and starting the session seems to clear up the condition.

Also, can I somehow confirm that my hunch about extraneous processing is correct to begin with? There is no state on the topology object that I can see.

I'm feeding the same audio and video renderer to all topologies, not sure if it matters.

As a workaround, I've implemented the logic where on video switch, the session is stopped, the code waits for the stopped event, then the topology is loaded and started. On testing I can't reproduce the frame skipping any longer. For now, I'll take the good news.

---

UPD: I've created a minimal example, sans the sample video files: https://gist.github.com/sevaa/88754eafffd68d8671ec593dc310faec

It relies on two video files, c:\Temp\SlowPlayer\a.m4v and c:\Temp\SlowPlayer\b.m4v (feel free to change the paths). If you try to reproduce, you could even use two copies of the same video there, as long as you can observe the video switching. Compile with Visual Studio 2022 as a Windows desktop project.

The frame skipping in my testing starts being visible around switch #10, gets really bad around #15.

Comment: According to your description, when you use `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE`,the previous topology is not explicitly stopped? If pTopology is not NULL, the topology is cleared only if pTopology matches the current topology (that is, only if pTopology points to the current topology).Pending topologies are not removed from the playback queue. If there is a pending topology on the queue, that topology will be loaded after the current topology is cleared.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite follow. The docs say if `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE` is specified, the topology currently in the session and all pending ones are **cleared**, and the new one is loaded into the session. So if I only ever call `SetTopology()` with `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE`, there are no queued topologies ever.